# Using a wallet generated from an out of sync client with a synced client

Tags: wallet

So I wanted to move my wallet from laptop to computer, and the Bitcoin client on my laptop is out of sync but I still generated a wallet.dat from it. If I then use this wallet.dat in an up to date client, will everything be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you will have to resync that wallet if it has pending transactions.